# Cannot catch exceptions when linking with certain libraries

Tags: c++, exception, gcc, linker, g++

I am unable to catch exceptions in my executable when linking with a certain static library. Instead, I get `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'`, `terminate called recursively`.

The library contains C and assembly sources compiled with gcc, as well as C++ sources compiled with g++. I'm guessing that this mixture is part of the problem.

Can anyone tell me exactly what the problem is? Let me know if I can provide any more info to home in on an explanation. Thanks.

Here is a simple example program that fails to catch the exception when I link with the library. Note that I am not calling any functions from the library. The mere act of linking the library causes this to fail.

baz.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    try {
        throw 7;
    } catch (int ex) {
        cout << "int: " << ex << endl;
    } catch (...) {
        cout << "..." << endl;
    }
}
```

Compiling / Linking:

```
g++ -o baz -ggdb baz.cpp -lxxx
```

Alternative compiling (mimicking how C++ sources in the library are compiled):

```
g++ -c -falign-functions=16 -D_REENTRANT -mtune=opteron -g -O2 -fPIC -Wall -Werror -Wpointer-arith -Wreturn-type -Wswitch -Wunused -Wundef -Wno-uninitialized -Wno-format -Wno-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-sign-compare -Wwrite-strings -DTRACE_SIMPLE -Wno-strict-aliasing -g -rdynamic -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_LARGEFILE64_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DXYZ_LITTLE_ENDIAN=1 -DXYZ_BIG_ENDIAN=0 -DXYZ=1 -DUMEM_TRACE=0 -DUSE_SYS_FLOAT -DINTEL_IPP_INLINE_MEMCHR=0 -DACCEL_TEST=1 -DXYZ -DUSE_XYZ_LIB -DACCEL_TEST=1 -o baz.o baz.cpp
```

The static library is created with `ar r` followed by `ranlib`.

Running:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
terminate called recursively
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Core backtrace:

```
#0  0x0000003ad4032625 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003ad4033e05 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000003ad80be991 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#3  0x0000003ad80bcbd6 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#4  0x0000003ad80bcc03 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#5  0x0000003ad80bcc86 in __cxa_rethrow () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#6  0x0000003ad80bea32 in __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#7  0x0000003ad80bcbd6 in ?? () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#8  0x0000003ad80bcc03 in std::terminate() () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#9  0x0000003ad80bcd22 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#10 0x0000000000400a9b in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffff3888) at baz.cpp:8
```

GCC version:

```
gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-ppl --with-cloog --with-tune=generic --with-arch_32=i686 --build=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-3) (GCC)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that particular compiler, but it likely assumes C functions are nonthrowing. The fact that it called `std::terminate` implies it inferred a `noexcept`. Basically, make sure exceptions don't come out of the C functions.

Comment: Well, without extra libraries, it's working well: http://ideone.com/WSkn4O So your code sample doesn't really _mimic_ what's happening with using your library. @VoidStar brought a good point what may be wrong with this library.

Comment: @VoidStar Does that apply in this case, since the exception should be both thrown and caught in main()? I'm not exactly sure what you mean about C functions. This example was compiled with g++, which compiles both .cpp and .c files as if they are C++ code. (Note that the library uses both gcc and g++ however.)

Comment: If you aren't actually running code from the linked lib it should make no difference... I assume a function in the lib is a C function and no exception can come out of (or through!!) any such function. Maybe there's something invisible happening...?  Also, can you look at the source for `#9  0x0000003ad80bcd22 in __cxa_throw () from /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6`? It may give a hint as to why it thought invoking `std::terminate` was appropriate.

Comment: What you can't do is pass a callback to a C++ function to a C function and then have that callback throw an exception. If you want to make that work, you have to modify the C code (specifically, build it with `-fexceptions`).

Comment: Possibly the library has a C startup in it (it shouldn't) so you end up  not having C++ startup done. To debug this, you could use the original object files instead of the library and figure out which one triggers the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks everyone. The problem turned out to be the presence of a C file in the library containing declarations/definitions for something like C++ language/library implementation functions. I'm not sure why this file was included, as removing it and recompiling the library did not cause any problems (at least is hasn't yet...). The example program was able to catch exceptions when linking with the recompiled library.

If anyone would like to post why the presence of these declarations/definitions caused exceptions not to be caught, feel free, and I may accept your answer. I will try to find out why this file was included to begin with. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Here is the contents of the file:

```
int __gxx_personality_v0(void);

int __gxx_personality_v0(void)
{
        return 1;
}

void __cxa_pure_virtual(void);

void __cxa_pure_virtual(void)
{
}

void _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE(void);
void _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE(void);
void _ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE(void);

void _ZTVN10__cxxabiv117__class_type_infoE(void) {}
void _ZTVN10__cxxabiv120__si_class_type_infoE(void) {}
void _ZTVN10__cxxabiv121__vmi_class_type_infoE(void) {}
```